# Ruby on Rails 4: Searchkick displaying all items instead of searched results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, search, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a `Forum` that `has_many` `:forum_threads` and `has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads`. So basically my Forums have their own Forum Threads that are related to that particular Forum topic. I've added Searchkick to handle the search form. Searchkick is working for my `Forum` table but not for my `ForumThread` table.

There is no error, it just renders out all of the forum threads instead of rendering the query that the form was given.

[Searchkick GitHub](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)

Here are my files:

**forum.rb**

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_threads
 has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

 searchkick text_start: [:title], suggest: [:title], autocomplete: [:title]

    def search_data         
            {
                title: title                    
            }
    end

end
```

**forums_controller.rb**

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController

 def index
    query = params[:q] || "*"
    @forums = Forum.search(query, suggest: true, fields: [:title],
                        boost_where: {specific: :exact})
 end

end
```

**views/forums/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag forums_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...' %>
<% end %>

  <% if @forums.suggestions.any? %>
    <p class="lead">
        <em>Did you mean: <strong><%= @forums.suggestions.first %></strong>?</em>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

**forum_thread.rb**

```
class ForumThread < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
 belongs_to :forum, counter_cache: true, touch: true
 has_many :forum_posts, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

 validates :subject, presence: true
 validates_associated :forum_posts

 searchkick text_start: [:subject], suggest: [:subject], autocomplete: [:subject]

    def search_data         
            {   
                subject: subject,   
                description: description                            
            }
    end

end
```

**forum_threads_controller.rb**

```
class ForumsController < ApplicationController

 def index
    query = params[:q].presence || "*"
        @forum_threads = @forum.forum_threads.search(query, suggest: true, fields: [:subject, :description])
 end

end
```

**views/forum_threads/index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag forum_forum_threads_path(<!-- something here? -->), method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...' %>
<% end %>


 <% if @forum_threads.suggestions.any? %>
    <p class="lead"><em>Did you mean: <%= @forum_threads.suggestions.first %>?</em></p>
 <% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :forums do
  resources :forum_threads do
    resources :forum_posts do
      member do
        put 'like', to: 'forum_posts#upvote'
        put 'dislike', to: 'forum_posts#downvote'
      end 
     end
    end
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a variable for suggestions to use in the view.

**forum_threads_controller.rb**

```
def index   
    query = params[:q].presence || "*"
        @forum_threads = ForumThread.search(query,
            where: { forum_id: @forum.id },
         fields: [:subject, :description], 
                                boost_where: {specific: :exact}, suggest: true, highlight: true)

    @forum_threads_suggestions = []
        if @forum_threads.empty? && @forum_threads.suggestions.any?
        @forum_threads_suggestions = ForumThread.search(@forum_threads.suggestions.first, fields: [:subject], suggest: true,
                    boost_where: {specific: :exact}, highlight: true)
        end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag forum_forum_threads_path, method: :get do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...' %>
            <% end %>

            <% if @forum_threads.suggestions.any? %>
                <p class="lead">
                    <em>
                        Did you mean: <strong><%= @forum_threads.suggestions.first %></strong>?
                    </em>
                </p>
            <% end %>

    </div>
    <!-- END SEARCH FORM -->    

                                    <!-- SHOW RESULTS AND SUGGESTIONS -->
        <p class="light-grey"><em>
            <%= pluralize @forum_threads.results.size, 'match' if params[:q].present? %>
            <%= pluralize @forum_threads.suggestions.size, 'suggestion' if @forum_threads.suggestions.any? %>
        </em></p>
                                    <!-- END RESULTS AND SUGGESTIONS -->

                                    <!-- SHOW FORUM THREADS -->
    <% (@forum_threads.presence || @forum_threads_suggestions).each do |forum_thread| %>
```

I wrote an **or** statement to either show all forum_threads or suggestions.

**forum_thread.rb)**

```
searchkick fields: [:subject], suggest: ['subject'], highlight: [:subject]

def search_data
    {
        forum_id: forum.id,
        forum_thread: @forum_thread,
        subject: subject
    }
end
```

I did the same thing for the forum model. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this so if someone else has something then please feel free to contribute.